# Can I use OpenGL in more than one language at the same time?

Tags: c#, c++, opengl

I have an OpenGL program in C#, but I also want to execute OpenGL functions from a C++ DLL.
Will the changes made by my C++ library take effect on the C# program?

**Edit: 
To be more clear, I want to share the same context of OpenGL for two languages.**

I am PInvoking functions of C++ that uses OpenGL from my C# code.

Comment: That seems like a bad idea. Keep the UI and graphics in one application, and let that application handle *everything* related to the UI and the graphics. Then you can off-load intensive *non* UI/graphics work to C++ libraries.

Comment: Yes,I will not do it. It was just curiosity. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want C++ and C# to share the opengl context, or have two contexts living side-by-side in the same application in separate languages?

Comment: I want them to share the same context

Comment: You mean 2 separate processes/programs sharing the same context? I don't think this question is clear.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude there's nothing wrong with a process written in Language X having OpenGL functions in a Dll (in language Y) as a UI library if they all share the same OpenGL context.   How do you think it works now?

Comment: @MickyD Having *all* actual OpenGL interfacing in a library is okay, or having all in the actual application. But mixing, with some OpenGL interfacing in the main application, and some in one (or more) libraries is really not a good idea. Neither from a design perspective, and least of all from a maintenance perspective.

Comment: Check last edit for a clearer question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Even then, OP's question is still possibly relevant, he could have a WPF application that happens to have an OpenGL GUI element that uses a DLL for rendering the content (using an existing engine, for example). Marshalling the context accross languages is still an issue here, even if the rendering is 100% in the C++ code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current OpenGL context is a thread-local global state.

What this means is that as long as the C++ and C# code are executing in the same thread, then OpenGL commands issued in either will be compatible.

However, if you are dealing with multiple/different threads, you will need to activate the OpenGL context in C++ (assuming it was created in C#), using `wglMakeCurrent()`. In order to do this, you'll have to propagate the proper handles somehow.